# How is Tsuyuri Kumin's name (五月七日くみん) read with 3 characters when it's made up of 4 kanji?

Tags: kanji, etymology, readings, names, multiple-readings

From the Chuunibyou anime, Kumin's last name is Tsuyuri (3 characters), but written as 五月七日 (4 kanji characters). How can this be? At first, I thought it might just be a chuuni thing, where you write a bunch of kanji and give it a different reading just to be edgy. But then I found that Tsuyuri is the standard reading for that 4-kanji combo. So yeah, how can that be?

Comment: Related: [Are there any words that are longer in kanji than in hiragana?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61993/5010)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Say we have a Japanese word that has a meaning, and we want to write it using kanji. If we cannot find any corresponding character, we have the option of combining characters and assigning the *combination* of those characters a reading. Maybe you've already seen this in words like 大人{おとな}, 明日{あした} and 七夕{たなばた}. This is called 熟字訓{じゅくじくん} and is a form of 当{あ}て字{じ}. There is no reason the number of kanji can't be greater than the number of kana in the reading, since the individual characters don't have anything to do with the reading.

Now, for this particular name, apparently there used to be a rainmaking festival on May 7th (五月七日) called つゆいり祭り, meaning "beginning of rainy season festival". May 7th in the Japanese lunar calendar corresponds to around the beginning of June in today's calendar, which is when the rainy season starts in Japan. Now, つゆいり went through some sound shifts and became つゆり or ついり.

Sources: [ピクシブ百科事典](https://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E3%81%A4%E3%82%86%E3%82%8A), [実用日本語表現辞典](http://www.practical-japanese.com/2018/09/blog-post_52.html)

Comment: There is a reason. It means that a semantic component has absolutely no phonetic component, requiring that unmarked silence be remembered and meaningful. No, that's actually impossible. The only way that it _does_ make sense is that the kanji is being used to mark an _entirely_ different native Japanese word with a simpler meaning, which is what happened here.

Comment: It's not _5th Moon, 7th Day_ that's being impossibly read as 3 sounds. It's that the kanji for that date is being used as a stand-in for the _actual_ words, a rainfest  that people could expect their audience to associate the written form of the date with.