# 日曜日，the different meanings and pronunciations of 日

Tags: pronunciation

I am not sure about the pronunciation rules of kanji in Japanese. I understand that there are several pronunciations for each kanji, and I am wondering how native speakers decide when to use which pronunciation. Example: In 日曜日, if I’m not wrong, the first 日 means SUN, pronounced as にち; the second 日 means DAY, pronounced as び. Is it the case in reality that when the same kanji expresses the same meaning in a word, it always has the same pronunciation? Referring back to the previous example, is it true that when 日 means Sun in a word, phrase or sentence, it always is pronounced にち？

Comment: Short answer: No, for example to say the 11th day is 十一日｛じゅういちにち｝, kanji pronunciation can be kind of unpredictable

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As is the case with other languages, Japanese people parse and read sentences based on **words** rather than **characters**. English speakers can pronounce the "rough" part of *rough*, *through* and *thorough* differently without thinking, and that's because they remember the pronunciations based on words. Likewise, 日曜日 is a very easy word meaning Sunday, and Japanese people don't need to worry about the reading of each character every time they see this word. There are even many [jukujikun](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24513/5010) like 大人（おとな）, 明日（あした）.

For some kanji, yes, a certain reading is strongly associated with a certain meaning. For example, the kanji 悪 typically means "bad" or "evil" when read as あく, but means "sick" or "hatred" when read as お. The kanji 楽 means "leisure" or "comfortable" when read as らく, and "music" when read as がく. (Most native speakers are unaware of this; again, they remember the pronunciations based on words.) However, in many other cases, the association of readings and meanings of a kanji can seem completely random, and you have to remember each word individually. Regarding 日, both にち and ひ can mean both "sun" and "day", but when it means "Japan", it's never read as ひ.

Comment: According to [the video](https://youtu.be/-12bzTZD1eY), each kanji has two meaning (also sound) so one must remember both of them? Do kanji have more than two meaning or only one?

Comment: @Istiak Yes you have to remember both readings, but there may not be two "meanings". And "two" is a lucky case. Here's a good starter: https://www.tofugu.com/japanese/onyomi-kunyomi/