# Difference between kanji にち and び

Tags: words, kanji

Google translate used same kanji for にち and び 日曜日. First syllable represents にち whereas last syllable represent び. But I can differentiate them both of them are looking same. They are pronounced differently cause the same syllable was used after よう?

Comment: Do you mean "character" by "syllable"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [日曜日，the different meanings and pronunciations of 日](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/68850/5010)

Comment: @aguijonazo hum! Yep.. I actually didn't know what they are actually called

Comment: I just commented because I have a right to close this question immediately without "voting"... Now I know you are fine with the existing answer, I can close this as a dupe.