# How does 方 becomes なた in 何方?

Tags: readings, multiple-readings

Most dictionaries say that 方 is read as ホウ, かた/がた, え.

But why does it change in [何方]{どなた} and is completely different in [何方]{どちら}? Are those some archaic readings or some 'synergetic' words that have nothing to do with the reading of its parts?

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24513/where-does-the-な-in-大人-otona-come-from

Comment: Honestly, なた is a common enough reading in words like 何方, 貴方, 其方, 此方, 彼方, I'm kind of surprised it's not listed as one of the normal readings (but then, none of those except 彼方 tend to be written in kanji these days). But it *is* listed as a reading for names.