# Does 悪 have a reading of 「いた」?

Tags: readings

In my immersion, I have come across the word [悪戯](https://jpdb.io/vocabulary/1151580/%E6%82%AA%E6%88%AF/%E3%81%84%E3%81%9F%E3%81%9A%E3%82%89?lang=english#a), which places an "いた" reading on 悪. However, when I look up the character ["悪"](https://jpdb.io/kanji/%E6%82%AA#a), I don't see "いた" listed as an acceptable reading.

Is this just a super rare reading of this character? Is there a mistake in this dictionary?

Comment: 熟字訓や当て字は聞かれたことがないんですか？

Comment: This is an example of 熟字訓 (じゅくじくん), which user5185 has explained nicely in an answer to another question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24513/where-does-the-な-in-大人-otona-come-from/24515#24515